# python interpretor automaticlly restarting without returning answer

Tags: python, recursion

Is there any reason why python interpretor will automatically restart when a recursive function is called? I'm programming a quick sort algorithm, and trying to sort a an large array of digits (order 10^4), but when I try to sort the full array python is restarting, i.e. giving me:

> > > > ============================== RESTART ==============================

and all the values/functions stored in memory disappears.
N.B. the code works fine for smaller values (<10^4). Is there fail safe been triggered due to the large amount of recursion?

added: python & IDLE info:

[image]

Comment: which python do you use?

Comment: edited question to include screenshot of python info

Comment: Would you post some code please?

Comment: You can see the recursion limit with `sys.getrecursionlimit()`. It should default to 1000, which should be plenty for a quicksort of 10000, so I guess your implementation isn't correct yet

Answer (score 1):

The most likely you got this message in IDLE. In IDLE, the "===RESTART===" is simply IDLE flushing its memory of the previous code.

UPDATE

If you entered IDLE by right-clicking on a program and choosing "Edit with IDLE," then these ====RESTART==== messages do not appear; IDLE is running in a slightly different mode. But everything still works.

Read [here](http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/idle/index.html) more about IDLE

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know why it is doing it and how I can stop it so it can sort my array for me.

Comment: It should not prevent you from "sorting your array". Please show us the code you are using to attempt to do so.

Comment: Idle normally (unless started with -n) runs user code in a user subprocess.  The RESTART line means that the subprocess has been restarted.  Regardless of how one starts Idle (without  -n) this occurs either when one selects Shell -> Restart Shell  Cntl+F6 or Run -> Run Module  F5.  It also occurs if the user process crashes from a program bug.  If one starts Idle from a command line (`python -m idlelib` or `... idlelib.idle` in 2.x, an error message might start there.